# How do I uninstall Django Evolution?

Tags: django, django-models, django-evolution

I installed it in my dev project. I would like to remove it and any trace of it in my database and my django app, not to mention my python install. I found it didn't quite do what I needed, but that's another topic, and I'm moving to South.

Can I just delete the evolution tables in my django db, and remove it from the app settings? Or is there more to it?

Comment: How exactly did you install it?

Comment: The standard way, python setup.py intall. And then settings.py syncdb.

Comment: Then you can delete the `evolution` tables, remove it from installed apps, and delete it from your site packages (or where ever it is on python path).

Comment: I tried that, and then ran syncdb and the evolution tables were made again. I can't find how it's doing this, I see no reference to evolution anywhere, I grepped everything.

Comment: Well, stale .pyc files come to mind, but other then that it is very puzzling indeed. Only removing it from INSTALLED_APPS should be enough to avoid creating tables for app.

Comment: I just tried removing all the pyc files for settings and models, and it still happens. Don't know what to say. I'm increasingly finding django somewhat flaky.

Comment: I figured it out, my iPython session had cached the settings

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1: Remove the python egg (example when installed with easy-install and python 2.5)**

```
bash$ locate easy-install.pth
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth

bash$ nano /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```

and delete the egg if it is there (was not there in my case).

```
bash$ easy_install -m django-evolution
```

see where the egg was installed, and finally remove it:

```
bash$ rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_evolution-0.6.1-py2.5.egg
```

---

**Part 2: remove django_evolution from django**

delete django_evolution from INSTALLED_APPS, i.e., open your settings.py and delete the line with 'django_evolution'

---

**Part 3: clean up DB**

To delete the django_evolution table:

Log in to your db (example with mysql):

```
bash$ mysql -u username -p

mysql> use XXX_django; # replace XXX_django by your django database (you can use "show databases;" to see which one is yours)
mysql> drop table django_evolution;
```